# Getting time with interval from array of time that is min by min

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, datetime

I got a logic like this:

```
let closingTime =  19:00
let openTime = 08:00

let timeArray['08:16', '08:17', '08:17'] ... until closingTime
```

So i got an array of time that is minute by minute.

The openTime is 08:00 but in my timeArray is starting at 08:16

So far i removed all the busy minutes from a time range openTime and closingTime

The first jobTask starts at 08:00 and finish as 08:00 + jobTask.duration

```
jobTask {
 duration : 15
 at_date: '2021-03-06 08:00:00'
}
```

This part is working great.

I'm trying to get timeArray and convert by an interval.

So i got 08:16, 08:17,  08:18... and i'm trying to make it display in a range by interval like this:

let interval = 30

the result i want is timeArray[08:16, 08:46, 09:16,... timeArray last hour].

Is there a way to solve this, i'm stuck with this :(

Is there math solution for this, to make it easy?

Code i've got :

```
        this.date.day.date = '2021-03-06'
        this.interval = 30
        let lastFreeTime = []
        timeArray.forEach((tme, index) => {
            let hour = tme.split(":")[0]
            let min = tme.split(":")[1]
            let fullTime = tme + ":00"
            if (!lastTime.length) {
                lastTime.push(fullTime)
                console.log("fullTime first", fullTime)
            } else {
                let lstime = lastTime[lastTime.length - 1]
                console.log("the last time", lstime)
                let nTme = moment(this.date.day.date + " " + lstime).add(
                    this.interval,
                    "m"
                )
                if (lastFreeTime.length <= 24) {
                    lastFreeTime.push(nTme)
                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: There are syntax errors in your code snippets.

Comment: Where's the code you've tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, assuming we are in a function that receives timeArray as argument, use this solution:

```
let base = timeArray[0].replace(':', '')  - 0;
let interval = 30;
function num(str) {
    return str.replace(':', '') - base;
} 
for (let i = timeArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)  if (num(timeArray[i]) % interval) timeArray.splice(i, 1);
```

This does not create unnecessary arrays and also does less type conversions than the other answer. Also it uses the correct base every time...

Comment: Make sure interval is an integer and not string. You can make integer from string with parseInt(stringContainingInt)...

Comment: item in that loop will be a string '08:16' what do you recommend for that?

Comment: @James Allan you only need to create a separate function to convert your strings to integers suitable for use with the reduce function. Then you can call map before filter.

Comment: Another alternative is to simply use an object to map the strings to integers and back again if you like. Its easy to do that. You don't want to use strings for computations...

Comment: this code worked great. I changed only a few lines because 08:00 when is splited and converted to int the 08 becomes 8.
so in the function str() is added :
if (result.length < 4) {
let newResult = "0" + result
return newResult.slice(0, 2) + ":" + newResult.slice(2)
} else {
return result.slice(0, 2) + ":" + result.slice(2)
}

Comment: The answer isn't valid javascript. Consider posting a runnable snippet with examples and an explanation of the OP's issue and how your code fixes it.

Comment: Glad it worked James. There may well be some rough edges still to work out. I did not test the code as I am typing from my phone. I was just showing how to go about the matter rather than presenting a copy-paste solution. One can always do 'minutes * 60 + hours' for a solution more resilient in edge cases...

Comment: @SeyiShoboyejo thx for your help, can you enplane what is that base of 1800?
The solution is working, its is starting 5 min later from the beginning hour.
it should start 08:16 but the first time how is 08:20, there is a diff of 5 min.
what do you recommend to make this work around ?

Comment: @James_Allan I have updated my answer to provide a more concrete solution. I was giving you rough hints before...

Comment: @SeyiShoboyejo thx, this updated code is way much better. It is starting at time i wanted in the example.